# how to reverse order of links in python jupyter notebook for each column

Tags: python, google-apps-script, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Hi i have a dataframe and i wish to reverse the url links in each column  where the last become the first

```
before
 
www.a.com, www.b.com, www.c.com, www.d.com, www.e.com
```

becomes

```
www.e.com, www.d.com, www.c.com, www.b.com, www.a.com
```

I have tried this code but it doesn't work as the commas have some problem, is there another way to solve it?

I have attached the error photos here: [image]

```
df['Image URLs']=df.URL.str.split().apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x[::-1]))
```

the dataframe is like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your dataframe has the following structure:

```py
[{"urls":"www.a.com,www.b.com"},{"urls":"www.c.com,www.d.com,www.e.com"}]
```

this will reverse the url order in each cell:

```py
df["urls"].apply(lambda x: ",".join(x.split(",")[::-1]))
```

The logic is the following:

- We first use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to execute a function to every cell of the column.
- We [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) the string value inside the cell to create a list of urls.
- We reverse that list (using [::-1])
- We [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) the elements of that list into a string with commas in between.